# IBM Social Business Toolkit SDK Development Environment Setup - Error servicing library GET request

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I've setup Java EE Eclipse as described in the following [IBM Social Business Toolkit SDK Development Environment Setup Youtube video](http://youtu.be/Cx4x1gkIPWE) which I found on the [OpenNTF.org page of the IBM SBTSDK](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Social%20Business%20Toolkit%20SDK). IBM Social Business Toolkit SDK Development Environment Setup

When I start Tomcat and open sbt.sample.web and call one of the examples I get the following error in the Tomcat log (see below).

I use the following version of the SBTSDK sbtsdk-1.0.0.20130228-2321.

Also the following projects have errors in my workspace and can't be build
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Project 'com.ibm.sbt.bootstrap211' is missing required source folder: 'src' com.ibm.sbt.bootstrap211        Build path  Build Path Problem

Any ideas what's going wrong?

```
    INFO: Server startup in 2190 ms
05.04.2013 11:30:55 com.ibm.sbt.jslibrary.servlet.LibraryServlet doGet
WARNUNG: Error servicing library GET request
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequestInterceptor
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.commons.runtime.beans.AbstractBeanFactory$Factory.create(AbstractBeanFactory.java:65)
    at com.ibm.commons.runtime.impl.AbstractContext.getBean(AbstractContext.java:142)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.endpoints.EndpointFactory.getEndpointUnchecked(EndpointFactory.java:87)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.endpoints.EndpointFactory.getEndpointUnchecked(EndpointFactory.java:68)
    at com.ibm.sbt.jslibrary.servlet.AbstractLibrary.populateEndpoints(AbstractLibrary.java:237)
    at com.ibm.sbt.jslibrary.servlet.AbstractLibrary.doGet(AbstractLibrary.java:168)
    at com.ibm.sbt.jslibrary.servlet.LibraryServlet.doGet(LibraryServlet.java:170)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at com.ibm.commons.runtime.servlet.BaseToolkitServlet.service(BaseToolkitServlet.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.ibm.sbt.util.SBTFilter.doFilter(SBTFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Exception you're getting (`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor`) it seems that you need to include `httpcore` jar library into your Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

For Project 'com.ibm.sbt.bootstrap211' is missing required source folder :

right click on the bootstrap211 project > Properties >  Java build path > Click on the source tab > De-delect '/src' if selected